# How to put text at the end of the input field with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want view plans text in input field right side how can I able to do that with bootstrap and CSS. view plans text is `<a>` tag and I am new to this bootstrap.

I just want to use the bootstrap to develop this input field is there any better way to do that?

[image]

Comment: [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) is a good referance...

Comment: it's not working , view plans are not going to the input box

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything native to do this in Bootstrap. You're probably best off rolling your own solution.

Using `<span>`'s for the 'View Plans' text and then positioning them with CSS should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.viewplans{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
}
```